# How do I delete a website that I added to my Home Screen

Tags: iphone

I have red other answers to this question and all I get is go to restrictions and turn something off. But I can’t find restrictions. How do I delete it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I am filling in the missing gaps so maybe this not the answer you are looking for.

When adding a certain website on your iOS device to the Home Screen it basically becomes an app icon. Therefore, you only have to long press the icon or the home screen itself. If you press the icon you will be presented with a small menu where you can select "edit home screen". Now all the app icons start to jiggle, you can rearrange and delete apps (and also this website bookmark) by clicking the small minus sign on the top left corer. If you long pressed the home screen (i.e. the background image) you will immidietaly see the jiggling.

[image]

Comment: When I edit the Home Screen and the apps start jiggling the website app just jiggles. There is no minus sign to delete it.

Comment: Are you using a beta version? This *should* work and I don't know any other way to achieve this.

Comment: What is a beta version?

Comment: Sort of a "test" version. When Apple (or any other software developer these days) programs their new software there will be bugs. To find those, Apple releases "beta" versions (pre-production sort of) to developers so that they report back to Apple whats working and what isn't. But since you don't know what it is, I highly doubt that you put this on your device...,